# Flex ANT tasks can't find my assets

Tags: apache-flex, ant

I'm attempting to compile my Flex project with an ANT build script.

One of my MXML components references an external XML data file, like this:

```
<mx:XML id="treeData" source="assets/data/help.xml" />
```

When I build the project using Flex Builder, it compiles fine. However, when I try to compile it using ANT, I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem finding external XML: assets/data/help.xml
```

How come ANT isn't finding the XML file? Apparently it knows the source path otherwise it would not have found the component to begin with. I added the source path to the target anyway, but it doesn't seem to have made any difference:

```
<source-path path-element="${SRC}" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Added a leading slash to the XML source parameter, and ANT was happy.